# How to Display Current Username In Form Field then Input from the Form into Another Table - "Forum Posts"

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am designing a simple forum. On the page for adding a topic, I found a way to automatically insert the active username where the user would otherwise type it in. The code I got from the textbook (Teach Yourself PHP, MySQL and Apache All in One, 5th Edition) originally had the user typing in their email address there. There's an error that causes a redirect from the page/code that processes the form. I am sure it is because that username cannot be inserted into the table at the database where the email address would have gone. The column ("post_owner") in the table is just varchar (150). Perhaps using "echo" in the form merely displays but adds no useable value to be processed??

I am trying to find a way to display the current username and have it go to "post_owner" in the database table. Can anyone show me how to display the active username and have it go to the relevant column (post_owner) in the database table? I will paste in the form, processing page, and table. Thanks.

The form, (addtopic.php)

```
<form method="post" action="do_addtopic.php">

    <p><label for="topic_owner"><n5 style="color: #ffe066; font-size: 14pt;">Your Username:<n5></label><br/>
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_id']; ?> name="topic_owner" size="30" maxlength="150" /></p>

    <p><label for="topic_title"><n5 style="color: #ffe066; font-size: 14pt;">Topic Title:<n5></label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="topic_title" name="topic_title" size=""
    maxlength="150" required="required" /></p>

    <p><label for="post_text"><n5 style="color: #ffe066; font-size: 14pt;">Post Text:<n5></label><br/>
    <textarea id="post_text" name="post_text" rows="" cols="" ></textarea></p>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button">Add Topic</button>
</form>
```

The processing page (do_addtopic.php)

```
<?php
include_once 'dbalt.php';
doDB();

//check for required fields from the form
if ((!$_POST['topic_owner']) || (!$_POST['topic_title']) ||
(!$_POST['post_text'])) {
header("Location: addtopic.html");
exit;
}

//create safe values for input into the database
$clean_topic_owner = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,
$_POST['topic_owner']);
$clean_topic_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,
$_POST['topic_title']);
$clean_post_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,
$_POST['post_text']);

//create and issue the first query
$add_topic_sql = "INSERT INTO forum_topics
(topic_title, topic_create_time, topic_owner)
VALUES ('".$clean_topic_title ."', now(),
'".$clean_topic_owner."')";

$add_topic_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $add_topic_sql)
or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

//get the id of the last query
$topic_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

//create and issue the second query
$add_post_sql = "INSERT INTO forum_posts
(topic_id, post_text, post_create_time, post_owner)
VALUES ('".$topic_id."', '".$clean_post_text."',
now(), '".$clean_topic_owner."')";

$add_post_res = mysqli_query($con, $add_post_sql)
or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
//close connection to MySQL
mysqli_close($mysqli);

//create nice message for user
$display_block = "<p>The <strong>".$_POST["topic_title"]."</strong>
topic has been created.</p>";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>New Topic Added</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>New Topic Added</h1>
<?php echo $display_block; ?>
<p>Click to <a href="topiclist.php">view</a> the topic listings.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

These are the two tables:

```
`forum_posts` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_text` text,
  `post_create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_owner` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL
)
`forumusers` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled input won't be submitted to server.

Try to remove `disabled="disabled"` from `<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_id']; ?> name="topic_owner" size="30" maxlength="150" />`

If you want to prevent the user to change the value, use `readonly` attribute instead.

See http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: That's it!!! Works like a charm! Thank you very much. I got that "disabled" stuff from another project where I was showing the date.

Comment: That other guy disappeared. I was telling him that I had tried various ways of defining a variable to use. He had suggested something I saw elsewhere earlier. From my login page: if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['password'];
        header("Location: loginsuccess.php");
    } else {
        $errormsg = "Incorrect Email or Password!!!";
    }

Comment: So, usr_id IS the username.

Comment: No problem :) @rob